Derivatives of diffeomorphism whose iterates on an open set converge to a point
Consider a smooth manifold $M$, a diffeomorphism $\varphi\in\mathrm{Diff}^\infty(M)$, and an open subset $B\subseteq M$. Suppose that, when restricted to $B$, $\varphi^n$ converges uniformly to a constant map with image $x\in M$.

For $\xi\in T_yM$ over some $y\in B$, do the tangent vectors $D_y\varphi^n(\xi)$ necessarily converge to the zero vector over $x$?

A while ago, I was convinced one could just look at curves inside $B$ with the given tangent vector at $y$, since the images of such curves under iterates of $\varphi$ will converge uniformly to $x$ and their derivatives will be the ones we want, but I'm no longer sure this guarantees that the derivatives go to $0$. This approach also doesn’t seem to work with the exponential map for a Riemannian metric we might put on $M$, since $\varphi$ is under no obligation to preserve geodesics in any way.
On the other hand, while there are obviously examples of functions converging uniformly to constants while their derivatives don't ($\frac{\sin(nt)}{n}$ being a standard example), I don't think I've ever seen an example with iterated diffeos, and it's hard for me to see how such a diffeo would work.

The answer is negative, at least for injective analytic maps $M\rightarrow M$. Consider $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow(-1,1)$ given by $f(x)=x-x^3$. There is a unique fixed point at the origin. Moreover, for any $0\neq x\in (-1,1)$, we have $|f(x)|=|x|(1-x^2)<|x|$. This shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f^{\circ n}(x)=0$ for any $x$ from the domain. The convergence is uniform: the image of $f$ is $$\left[f\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{-2}{3\sqrt{3}},f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\right]\subset\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
on which $f$ is strictly increasing. Thus
$$
f^{\circ n}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\leq f^{\circ n}(x)\leq f^{\circ n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\quad \forall n\geq 1, x\in (-1,1).
$$
This implies the uniform convergence $f^{\circ n}\rightrightarrows 0$ due to $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{\circ n}\left(\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=0$. But notice that $x=0$ is a fixed point at which the derivative is $1$, so $\left(f^{\circ n}\right)'(0)=1$ for any $n\geq 1$.
Here, $f$ is not a diffeomorphism, but restricting it to the interval between the critical values yields an injective self-map of $\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$. The same holds there too: the iterates converge uniformly to the constant map zero while their derivatives are all equal to $1$ at $x=0$.
Remark) In the complex plane, $z=0$ is a parabolic fixed point of $z\mapsto z-z^3$. The rays $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ lie in this parabolic basin of attraction. The uniform convergence observed above of course fails over complex numbers because the map admits repelling petals there (cf. Chapter 10 of Milnor's book).
Added) Building on the idea of parabolic fixed points which are topologically attracting over the reals, I slightly change the example above so that it becomes a diffeomorphism as well.

The map $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}:x\mapsto x-x^3+x^5$ is a
diffeomorphism satisfying $f^{\circ
n}\restriction_{(-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)}\rightrightarrows 0$ where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number. But $(f^{\circ
n})'(0)=1\quad\forall n\geq 1$.


The map is bijective since it is an odd-degree polynomial whose derivative $f'(x)=1-3x^2+5x^4$ is always positive. As for the dynamical aspects, $|f(x)|=|x|(1-x^2+x^4)<|x|$ for any non-zero element of $(-1,1)$.  Therefore, the orbit of any point from intervals $(0,1)$ or $(-1,0)$ (which are invariant under $f$) must converge. That limit must be a fixed point in $(-1,1)$, thus equal to $0$. We conclude that $f^{\circ
n}\restriction_{(-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)}\rightarrow 0$ pointwise. The convergence is uniform over compact subsets because for any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, due to $f'>0$ one has
$$
f^{\circ n}(-1+\epsilon)\leq f^{\circ n}(x)\leq f^{\circ n}(1-\epsilon)\quad \forall n\geq 1, x\in (-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon),
$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{\circ n}(\pm(1-\epsilon))=0$ as just established.
Remark) Notice that $f$ extends to a diffeomorphism of the circle $\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ via $\infty\mapsto\infty$. So the answer is negative even when $M$ is a closed manifold. Moreover, this map is the very special case of a parabolic fixed point which nevertheless is attracting on the real line. So I wonder if the answer to the original question is positive if we work in the holomorphic category.

Thanks for the answer, but isn’t your $f:(-1,1)\to (-1,1)$ not a diffeomorphism from $(-1,1)$ to itself?

@user815293 Ture. But it is a local diffeomorphism around $x=0$. I will try to think of a diffeomorphism from an open interval onto itself. I am going to amend my answer if that idea works.
